# API Яндекс Доставки - не понимаю

Tags: php, curl, яндекс-доставка

Делаю все по этой документации: https://tech.yandex.ru/delivery/doc/dg/reference/get-sender-orders-docpage/

```
$href = 'https://delivery.yandex.ru/api/last/getSenderOrders';
$methodKey = '440b1fad8641995b1257f3034534b470a447287b37234534579b63cef3c14de28d015db8ac1e';
$client_id = '55781';
$sender_id = '32654';

$date = array();
$secret_key = md5(getPostValues($date) . $methodKey);
$date2 = array(
'secret_key' => $secret_key,
'client_id' => $client_id,
'sender_id' => $sender_id,
);
$my = http_build_query($date2);
$href2 = 'https://delivery.yandex.ru/api/last/getSenderOrders?'.$my;
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $href2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
) );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($date)); 
$out = curl_exec($curl);
$er = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    print_r(json_decode($out));

function getPostValues($data)
{    
    if (!is_array($data)) return $data;    
    ksort($data);    
    return join('', array_map(function($k)
                            {
                              return getPostValues($k);
                            }, 
                $data));
  }
```

Вроде, все просто, но, видимо, я чего-то делаю не так. 
Поправьте меня, пожалуйста.

Comment: В массив $date для генерации secret_key нужно передавать весь массив запроса?
Или там только client_id и sender_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам себе отвечу) Затупил с передачей массива и формированием секретного кода.

```
$href = 'https://delivery.yandex.ru/api/last/getOrderInfo';
$methodKey = '440b1fad8641995b1257f30asb470a4472f89a61fasdf565bcb63437ce15fdaf86fc810';
$client_id = '1234';
$sender_id = '0980';
$order_id = '3792097';

$date = array(
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'sender_id' => $sender_id,
    'order_id'  => $order_id,
);
 $secret_key = md5(getPostValues($date) . $methodKey2);
 $date2 = array(
    'secret_key' => $secret_key,
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'sender_id' => $sender_id,
    'order_id'  => $order_id,
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $href);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
) );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($date2)); 
$out = curl_exec($curl);
$er = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print_r($out);

function getPostValues($data)
  {    
if (!is_array($data)) return $data;    
ksort($data);    
return join('', array_map(function($k)
                            {
                              return getPostValues($k);
                            }, 
                $data));
}
```